# how to use get_field_name in external ajax handler

Tags: widgets, ajax

I am loading new form fields from Ajax when I click on radio button in my custom widget. In Ajax callback handler, I need to use [get_field_name](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_field_name) and get_field_id widget class methods. get_field_name method is return in [WP_Widget](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-includes/widgets.php#L109) class. So I try to get the instant of that class. But I unable to do that. So please someone help me how to use it in external class.

```
   function wp_ajax_suport(){

    add_action('wp_ajax_my_func', 'my_func');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_func', 'my_func');
    }    
    add_action( 'init', 'wp_ajax_suport' );

    function my_func(){

    <input type="text" name="<?php $this->get_field_name('name'); ?>">
    }
```

Comment: just register your ajax actions properly - using external files causes more issues than it would serve any use.

Comment: @syslogic: i am using registering ajax in proper way. I unable to use the function get_field_name inside ajax handler. Check my code sample

Comment: you have to register both, frontend and backend hooks, when using wp-ajax on the frontent. seems unlogical - but that's the way it works.

Comment: Syslog it not related to my question

Comment: @syslogic: what you mean by proper way!. I understood what you saying front/back end ajax register. I am already doing it. But my actual question is entirely different from here. I want to access `$this->get_field_name` function in ajax handler.

Comment: of course it is... you probably just don't get it - why produce such crap, when the proper way to do it (means: doing it WP style) is so simple? Adding complexity while it isn't required ...is only causing problems.

Comment: the proper way is the register both hooks frontend AND backend... when using WP-AJAX on the frontend... you just need to add the _priv hook (that's why I mean with backend hook).

Comment: @syslogic: check my code I updated. Still I am doing everything in backend with user access. so my question is different.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to use  ajax for showing some fields on form in widget?
Can't it be done using simple show hide using jquery. See below. Not tested , just to give insight.

HTML

```
<input type="radio" id="someradio" />
<div id="somediv" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" name="<?php $this->get_field_name('name'); ?>">
</div>
```

Jquery

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    jQuery('#someradio').on('click',function(){
        jQuery('#somediv').toggle();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. But I loading form fields throw ajax. because it calls api. I don't want to waste the api calles for every load of the page. So I am calling ajax and loading the new dynamic form fields depends on selecting the checkbox. So I want to know how to use the  get_field_name out side or is there a way to store the widget without that name function.